# Extract values between parenthesis from NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I have an NSString that will be something like "xxxx (yyyyy)" where x and y can be any character. I'd like to extract just the y from inside the parenthesis. I managed to extract the x using a NSScanner but I haven't figured out the proper way to extract out the y.

Comment: If x and y can be parentheses, you're in for a world of hurt.

Comment: Sounds like you want regex...

Answer (score 16):

Just to be complete:

If you are absolutely sure of the format of your output you can use the array methods:

```
NSString *inputString; // this is in the form "xxxx(yyyy)"

NSCharacterSet *delimiters = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"()"];
NSArray *splitString = [inputString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:delimiters];

NSString *xString = [splitString objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *yString = [splitString objectAtIndex:1];
```

Of course, you need to be sure that the delimiting characters don’t exist in the inputString

Comment: There is a minor typo in the yString declaration (ojbectAtIndex) and a missing semicolon on the splitString declaration. But otherwise worked perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @TPoschel Thanks - I wouldn't have minded if you'd made the corrections yourself. :)

Answer (score 5):

Easiest way would be to use RegExKit:

http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/

Then you'd do something like:

```
[@"xxxx(yyyyy)" getCapturesWithRegexAndReferences:@"\\((.*)\\)",@"$1", &extractedString,nil];
```

and extractedString would contain whatever was in parenthesis.

Answer (score 5):

[Scan up to](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScanner/scanUpToString:intoString:) the ‘(’, then [scan it](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSScanner/scanString:intoString:), then scan up to the ')'. The result of the last scan is `yyyy`.

Comment: A solution without regex!  Hear, hear!

Answer (score 1):

you might have a look at PKTokenizer in ParseKit:

http://parsekit.com